# error catching help in vb

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

having issues with error catching, I have been trying to fix this but not sure why its not working.

Update: I did not go in to much detail sorry about that.

On line six the user is mean to enter a number but if a user enters a letter the program crashes. I normally use double.tryparse and that works great, but for some reason getting a "Error 1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'TryParse' accepts this number of arguments" error message

```
   Private Sub quadraticEquation()
   Dim a, b, c, d As Double
    Dim x1, x2, stra, strb, strc As String
    Console.WriteLine("ax^2 + bx + c = 0")
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a")
    stra = Console.ReadLine()
    a = Double.Parse(stra)
    If IsNumeric(stra) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter b")
        strb = Console.ReadLine()
        b = Double.Parse(strb)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input")
        Call quadraticEquation()
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter c")
```

Comment: What is the error, and on what line??? You should use `Double.TryParse()` instead. It will return True if the value could be parsed to a double.

Comment: If you're having trouble with error catching, then add some error handling and debug through the code.

Comment: You need to try and give as much information to narrow down the problem as possible for questions on here.  In your code: there is no point testing IsNumeric(stra) AFTER doing Double.Parse(stra) - the parse should be inside the if.  And if there is a bad input you don't want to call the quadraticEquation sub again, that's really tangled.  Better to put the hole thing in some sort of `While` or `Repeat` loop

Comment: sorry about that I have now updated my post, I will make some changes to the code and see what happens

Comment: You forgot to update your code in the post, the error message isn't enough. TryParse can be used like this: `If Double.TryParse(stra, Nothing) = True Then` where it returns _True_ if the parsing succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check if stra is numeric and only if its numeric parse it to a double type, you try to parse non numeric value to double and its not possible that is why exception is thrown.

```
   If IsNumeric(stra) Then
            a = Double.Parse(stra)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter b")
            strb = Console.ReadLine()
            b = Double.Parse(strb)
        Else
            Console.Write("Invalid input")
        End If
```